# Support: Trouble deploying to IIS properly from DevOps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-devops

I'm trying to build, release, and deploy to IIS.  I have a couple problems.  The main problem is that it's deploying to my IIS server in a format I'm not familiar with.  I've attached a screenshot below.

What I really want to be in that directory is the contents of `EazeeApp.UI.zip\Content\d_C\a\1\s\Source\EazeeApp.UI\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp`

If I copy that file to the root of my website folder, viola.

This is my build config:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

This is my `IIS Web App Deploy` setup

```
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.WebsiteName’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972

steps:
- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'IIS Web App Deploy'
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: '$(Parameters.WebsiteName)'
    Package: '_EazeeApp\drop'
    XmlVariableSubstitution: True
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Package: '_EazeeApp\drop'
```

You're currently pointing it to the folder but it should point to the web publish package you want to deploy to the destination site

```
Package: '_EazeeApp\drop\EazeeApp.UI.zip'
```